# Mvc dotnet core knockout model not updating UI

Tags: html, model-view-controller, knockout.js, asp.net-core

If I want to update the model, the surface does not update, but the model already.

After the save method, the model is updated but not the graphical interface.

Does anyone know how I update the model so that the view also takes the changes.

View:

```
    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(this.Model));

    var code = document.getElementById("editor-area");

    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-csrc",
                lineWrapping: true,
                theme: 'the-matrix'});

            model.save = function() {
                model.CurrentSnippet.Code(editor.getValue());
                var url = "/Snippet/Save";

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { viewModel: ko.toJS(model.CurrentSnippet)},
                    }).done(function(response) {
                        model = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.fromJSON(response));
                    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    alert("fail: " + textStatus);
                });
            }

    var bindContainer = document.getElementById("editor");
    ko.applyBindings(model, bindContainer);
```

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Save(ViewModelSnippet viewModel)
    {
         var model = Mapper.MappeViewModelSnippetZuSnippet(viewModel);
         _snippetRepository.Save(model);
         var returnModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ViewModelSnippets { Selection = Guid.NewGuid(), Snippets = Mapper.MappeSnippetsZuViewModelSnippets(_snippetRepository.GibAlleSnippets()) , CurrentSnippet = viewModel});
         return Json(returnModel);
    }
```

Chrome inspector/console:

Model befor save:

```
{CurrentSnippet: {…}, __ko_mapping__: {…}, Selection: ƒ, Snippets: ƒ, save: ƒ, …}
CurrentSnippet
:
{SnippetId: ƒ, Name: ƒ, Description: ƒ, Code: ƒ, Modified: ƒ}
Selection
:
ƒ c()
Snippets
:
ƒ c()
clear
:
ƒ ()
deploy
:
ƒ ()
load
:
ƒ ()
save
:
ƒ ()
snippetClick
:
ƒ (data)
__ko_mapping__
:
{ignore: Array(0), include: Array(1), copy: Array(0), observe: Array(0), mappedProperties: {…}, …}
__proto__
:
Object
```

After save:

```
{CurrentSnippet: {…}, __ko_mapping__: {…}, Selection: ƒ, Snippets: ƒ}
CurrentSnippet
:
{SnippetId: ƒ, Name: ƒ, Description: ƒ, Code: ƒ, Modified: ƒ}
Selection
:
ƒ c()
Snippets
:
ƒ c()
__ko_mapping__
:
{mappedProperties: {…}, ignore: ƒ, include: ƒ, copy: ƒ, observe: ƒ, …}
__proto__
:
Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to update view model instead of recreation on ajax.done:

```
            }).done(function(response) {
                // Created here a model instance is not bound to the UI
                model = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.fromJSON(response));
            }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
```

You can do it like described in the mapping [plugin documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

> ```
> var data = {
>     name: 'Scot',
>     children: [
>         { id : 1, name : 'Alicw' }
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> You can map this to a view model without any problems:
>
> ```
> var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
> ```
>
> Now, let’s say the data is updated to be without any typos:
>
> ```
> var data = {
>     name: 'Scott',
>     children: [
>         { id : 1, name : 'Alice' }
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> Two things have happened here: name was changed from Scot to Scott and
>   children[0].name was changed from Alicw to the typo-free Alice. You
>   can update viewModel based on this new data:
>
> ```
> ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
> ```